# There is very little documentation on NSTextCHeckingKey, what is it and how is it used?

Tags: swift

Ive come across some code that I'm trying to decipher.

```
case addressComponents([NSTextCheckingKey: String]?)
```

However there is very little documentation on NSTextCheckingKey. Can anyone be of assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This structure is used to select the kind of information that you want to extract from a string using [NSDataDetector](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatadetector)

In your code I suppose that `addressComponents` is a dictionary whose values conform to a human-readable adress.

Maybe it contains the keys `.city, .country, .name, .state, .street and .zip`